# How do I cite a UN Conference Fact sheet correctly?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

So there is a fact sheet by the United Nations uploaded from one of their conferences.
You can see it [here](https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Ocean-fact-sheet-package.pdf).
How do I cite this correctly? It is not an article or anything similar.

I currently do it like this:

```
@manual{UNFactSheet,
    author        = "{United Nations}",
    title         = {Factsheet: People and Oceans},
    year          = {2017},
    url           = {https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Ocean-fact-sheet-package.pdf}
}
```

Is this more or less correct, or should I do something else?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. (Not all bib styles recognize the `url` field name.)

Comment: I use `\bibliographystyle{cas-model2-names}`. It is the typical elsevier template and it seems to recognize the url field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen the `@manual` entry type, which IMNSHO isn't an entirely obvious choice; I would have chosen the `@misc` type. However, if you do want to stick with the `@manual` entry type, you could (should?) make use of the fact that this entry type recognizes the fields `organization` and `address` to write

```
@manual{UNFactSheet,
    author        = "{United Nations}",
    title         = {{Factsheet: People and Oceans}},
    organization  = {The Ocean Conference, United Nations},
    address       = {New York},
    year          = {2017},
    url           = {https://www.un.org/sustainabledevelopment/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Ocean-fact-sheet-package.pdf}
}
```

And, be sure to load the `xurl` package to allow arbitrary linebreaks in the long URL string.

Comment: I somewhat arbitrarily chose it because I saw it in another question when people talked about 'fact sheets' in another question. I assume the url goes into the 'howpublished' part of `@misc`?

Comment: @AkariYukari - With the `cas-model2-names` bib style, using the `url` field for URL strings should be fine.